# Does Mathematica limit the size of a set of permutation group generators?

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields

I tried to generate general and special linear groups PGL2 and PSL2 over finite fields using straightforward algorithms over finite fields: The generators are permutations defined as the additive group, multiplicative group, and inversion over the field.
Although my algorithms work properly for fields of size < 100 (PSL2), resp. <74 (PGL2), for larger input they generated substantially smaller permutation groups. For instance,
(*full code below*)

```
GroupOrder@PSL2[97]
```

gives the expected results  456288, but

```
GroupOrder@PSL2[101]
```

gives 5100.

Moreover, for n=97 my code generates counterintuitively smaller PGL2[97] than PSL2[97]

```
GroupOrder@PGL2[97]
```

answers 9408 (the correct size is 912576=2*456288)

I believe the error is neither algebraic nor in my code, because it only appears from a certain number upwards and moreover, the limit is smaller for pgl than for psl. Therefore I hypotheses I  exceed the maximum allowed number of generators. Is it true?

**code for PGL2 and PSL2**

```
<< FiniteFields`
PGL2[q_] :=Module[{pField = (FactorInteger@q)[[1, 1]], 
rField = (FactorInteger@q)[[1, 2]]},
fiFiQ = GF[pField, rField];  (* define the finite field *) 
elementsFiFoQ = fiFiQ /@ Tuples[Range[0, pField - 1], rField]; (* list of elements of the finite field *) 
enumeratedElementsFiFiQ=MapThread[RuleDelayed, {elementsFiFoQ , Range[q]} ]; (* enumerate elements of the field *) 
addPerm=PermutationCycles /@ (Outer[Plus, elementsFiFoQ, elementsFiFoQ] /. enumeratedElementsFiFiQ /. {0 -> 1}); (* permutations corresponding to the additive group *) 
multPerm=PermutationCycles /@ (Outer[Times, elementsFiFoQ[[2 ;;]], elementsFiFoQ] /. enumeratedElementsFiFiQ /. {0 -> 1}); (* permutations corresponding to the multiplicative group *) 
invPerm=PermutationCycles@(({q + 1} ~ Join~(1/# & /@ elementsFiFoQ[[2 ;;]]) ~ Join~{1} ) /. enumeratedElementsFiFiQ /. {0 -> 1}); (* permutation corresponding to the inversion *) 
PermutationGroup@(addPerm \[Union] multPerm \[Union] {invPerm})]
   



PSL2[q_] :=Module[{pField = (FactorInteger@q)[[1, 1]], 
rField = (FactorInteger@q)[[1, 2]]},
fiFiQ = GF[pField, rField];  (* define the finite field *) 
elementsFiFoQ = fiFiQ /@ Tuples[Range[0, pField - 1], rField]; (* list of elements of the finite field *) 
enumeratedElementsFiFiQ=MapThread[RuleDelayed, {elementsFiFoQ , Range[q]} ]; (* enumerate elements of the field *) 
addPerm=PermutationCycles /@ (Outer[Plus, elementsFiFoQ, elementsFiFoQ] /. enumeratedElementsFiFiQ /. {0 -> 1}); (* permutations corresponding to the additive group *) 
multPerm=PermutationCycles /@ (Outer[Times, elementsFiFoQ[[2 ;;]], elementsFiFoQ] /. enumeratedElementsFiFiQ /. {0 -> 1}); (* permutations corresponding to the multiplicative group *) 
invPerm=PermutationCycles@(({q + 1} ~ Join~ (-1/# & /@ elementsFiFoQ[[2 ;;]]) ~ Join~{1} ) /. enumeratedElementsFiFiQ /. {0 -> 1}); (* permutation corresponding to the -1/x *) 
PermutationGroup@(addPerm \[Union] multPerm \[Union] {invPerm})]
```